# Remove excess space in tkinter grid

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, removing-whitespace

```
import Tkinter as Tk

master = Tk.Tk()

water = Tk.PhotoImage(file="water.gif")
desert = Tk.PhotoImage(file="desert.gif")
tundra = Tk.PhotoImage(file="tundra.gif")
forest = Tk.PhotoImage(file="forest.gif")
plains = Tk.PhotoImage(file="plains.gif")
swamp = Tk.PhotoImage(file="swamp.gif")
mountains = Tk.PhotoImage(file="mountains.gif")
island = Tk.PhotoImage(file="island.gif")

labels = []

for i in gameMap.tiles:
    x = i.Pos[0]
    y = i.Pos[1]
    z = i.climate
    if z == "Water":
        texture = water
    elif z == "Desert":
        texture = desert
    elif z == "Tundra":
        texture = tundra
    elif z == "Forest":
        texture = forest
    elif z == "Plains":
        texture = plains
    elif z == "Mountains":
        texture = mountains
    elif z == "Swamp":
        texture = swamp
    elif z == "Island":
        texture = island
    label = Tk.Label(master, image=texture)
    labels.append([label, x, y])

for i in labels:
    i[0].grid(row=i[1], column=i[2])

master.mainloop()
```

This is a snippet of code covering the loop that generates the display window. The intent is to produce a grid of square images representing a randomly generated map. Earlier in the code, tiles are randomly generated as instances of the class Tile() and appended to a list in gameMap.tiles.

gameMap.tiles.Pos is a 2-element list containing an int x and y coordinate respectively.

gameMap.tiles.climate is a str set earlier to one of eight options.

The code functions as intended. The only problem is that the square gifs are surrounded by a few pixels of whitespace, ruining the illusion of interconnectedness. How can I change the grid layout to remove this whitespace?

P.S. I am aware that this segment of code is clunky (e.g. z is totally unnecessary), but I have been roundabout for debugging purposes. It will be fixed when I am able to remove this whitespace.

Comment: If `z` isn't necessary to reproduce this problem, please remove it from the example. See [mcve]. It would also help if  you describe what you've tried. Widgets and the grid command all have many documented options controlling borders, padding, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When creating your Label, set `highlightthickness=0`, also provided that `z` is of a predefined list of values, you could create a dictionary of the images, and then retrieve that using `z` as the key, saving many lines and also possibly clarity. If you are not concerned with the use of `eval`, then you could use `texture=eval(z.lower())`, removing the need for the unnecessary `if` statements.